# How to install the koding IDE in a personal server?

Tags: vps, koding

I found the koding IDE code in their github repository:

https://github.com/koding/IDE

but i can't find a way to install it, and README doesn't help much.

Some one knows how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to run Koding is to install docker-compose which can be found here (Requires docker-compose version >= 1.6). For the rest you can follow these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/koding/docker-compose.git
koding-docker-compose
cd koding-docker-compose
docker-compose up -d
```

Now you are able to access Koding via port 8090 (e.g. localhost:8090) on your host.

## Update

Running Koding on Local Machine

This is if you don't want to do docker-compose way and install everything locally, (not recommended).

### Software Prerequisites

Go v1.7
Node.js v0.10
CoffeeScript v1.8.0
Supervisor
Start developing

Follow these steps for running the instance:

```
git clone https://github.com/koding/koding.git /your/koding/path
cd /your/koding/path
node -v # make sure your node version is not greater than `0.10.x`
npm -v # make sure your npm version is 2.15.x
coffee -v # make sure your coffeeScript version must be 1.8
npm install
```

You should have packages ready for running build specific scripts.

```
./configure # create necessary config files
./run install # start to install dependencies
./run buildservices # build the services
./run # run all services
```

As a result, you will have a file watcher watching your backend files (both node, and golang) and restart services when it's necessary. Now open up another terminal and run following commands:

```
cd /your/koding/path
cd client # move into frontend client folder
npm install # install client dependencies
make # this will run a client watcher for you
```

Right now you should have 2 different watchers for (1) your backend files, (2)for your frontend client files. Now you can navigate to to see your local Koding instance. Enjoy!

Comment: `docker-compose up -d` 
worked great, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Its not working for me. I am using digital ocean vps. Do you have any tip for me.